# Check whether cmis:contentStreamFilename is Orderable

Tags: cmis, opencmis, dotcmis

The [CMIS 1.1 standard](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/cs01/CMIS-v1.1-cs01.html) says at 2.1.4.3.3 that `cmis:contentStreamFileName` has a `Orderable` property which CMIS repositories can choose to set to true or false.

As a CMIS client having a session on a particular repository, how to tell whether this repository has an `Orderable` of true or false for `cmis:contentStreamFileName`.

Preferably using DotCMIS or PortCMIS or OpenCMIS.

The [Chemistry samples website](https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/capabilities/index.html) has samples showing how to get repository capabilities, but not of this kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the definition of types and then for the type you are interested in, check the property you are interested in, like this Java example using OpenCMIS:

```
ObjectType typeDef = getSession().getTypeDefinition("cmis:document");
Map<String, PropertyDefinition<?>> propDefs = typeDef.getPropertyDefinitions();
PropertyDefinition<?> propDef = propDefs.get("cmis:contentStreamFileName");
System.out.println(String.format("Is %s orderable? %s", propDef.getId(), propDef.isOrderable()));
```

Running this against Alfresco 5.2 CE and against Chemistry 0.11 returns false in both cases:

```
Is cmis:contentStreamFileName orderable? false
```